# Python Arcade caches textures when requested not to

Tags: python, caching, arcade

I'm trying to change the background texture in an Arcade app, however, even though I requested Arcade not to cache textures, it seems as though it does. This is my code:

```py
class Application(arcade.Window):
    # ...

    def on_draw(self):
        if should_change_back:   # logic for when is written elsewhere
            # get img and edit it
            new_imgPath = self.choose_img()
            new_img = self.edit_img(new_imgPath)
            
            # save edited image in directory
            new_img.save(self.tmpImgPath)

        # load texture
        arcade.start_render()
        background = arcade.load_texture(self.tmpImgPath, can_cache=False)
        arcade.draw_lrwh_rectangle_textured(self.l, self.r, self.w, self.h, background)

    # ...
```

Every `on_draw`, if the app decided it should change the background, it chooses a new image, edits it in a random way (implemented in `edit_img`) and saves it in a certain path (**always the same path**). I believe that since Arcade sees this is the same path, it thinks the texture is the same and uses its cache, even though it isn't supposed to.

I have tried loading a different texture before re-loading the new one, as well as using `arcade.cleanup_texture_cache()` before loading the new texture, and neither worked.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not work for me as well. Probably it's an Arcade issue.

Comment: We're rewriting the entire texture cache in arcade 2.7. That doesn't help you now, but at least you know.